# node.js - The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer with http module

Tags: ios, node.js

these day I'm new to node.js and leanrning them from Youtube vid
I had a plan to express image file to webbrowser 
here is something wrong (I've already add image file in my folder)
and then I was trying to resolve this problem by searching google 
but I hadn't found out.
It's first time to make a new account

it's the code

```
var http=require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer();

var host = '192.168.0.42';

var port = 3000;
server.listen(port,host,50000,function(){
    console.log('웹서버 실행됨');
});

server.on('connection',function(socket){
var addr = socket.address();
console.log('클라이언트가 접속했습니다. : %s, %d', addr.address,addr.port);
});

server.on('request',function(req,res){
console.log('클라이언트 요청이 들어왔습니다.');
var filename = "coronavirus.png";
fs.readFile(filename, function(err,data){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"image/png"});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();

    });



});
```

Comment: I am not sure about the error you are getting but if any, it's always good to share it as well in your future questions. What caught my attention was the path you are passing to the `readFile` method; have you tried including the / as in /your_file_path and test that? You need to pass a relative or absolute path to the method.

Comment: ohh yeah I try it. thanks a lot!!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful to you, please accept it (green check)

Answer (score 0):

your `readFile` needs to include an absolute or relative path.
try with a forward "/" as in `/your_file_path` or resolve with a cross-platform solution using `__dirname` + your file_path.

[From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: oh yeah I added some code like { if (err) throw err } already I used absolute path and then I was faced with another problem [ Error : no such file or directory, open 'coronavirus.png] but it was included with my directory

Comment: Çan you update your code sample above to account for your error handling inside the `fs readFile` callback. Can you also share your file directory? Where is this png file you want to render? If it is in the root, in the same lavel where your server is, your file must be there `./your_image_must_be_there`. Try with "/" and or with a single "./" or "../" depending on where your file is...